# JS не видит знак

Tags: javascript

Нужно с помощью цикла вывести чётные числа с 2 до 10.

```
for (var i = 2, i <= 10, i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

В консоли выдаёт

> SyntaxError. Unexpected token <=.

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно точки с запятой использовать вместо запятых.

> **Синтаксис выражения for**
>
> ```
> for ([инициализация]; [условие]; [финальное выражение])выражение
> ```

```js
for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Точно) Не заметил